# How to get value of JLabel inside a loop using mouseClicked?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

I made a modification of my simple program, instead of using table I created my customized code to display my list using `JPanel`. My problem now is when I clicked button it gives me the value of last list.

This is my method look like:

```
private void customize(List<Student> students) {
    panelStudentHolder.removeAll();
    panelStudentHolder.revalidate();
    panelStudentHolder.repaint();
    for (Student student : students) {
        panelStudentHolder.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        panelStudentHolder.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Student List", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.ABOVE_TOP, new java.awt.Font("Century Gothic", 1, 14))); // NOI18N
        panelStudent = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        lblStudent = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        btnBackUp = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnEdit = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnBlock = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        lblStudent.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Century Gothic", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        lblStudent.setText(student.toString()+" >> "+student.getId());

        btnEdit.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/icons8-view-20.png"))); // NOI18N
        btnEdit.setText("Edit");
        btnEdit.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                System.out.println(" "+lblStudent.getText());
            }
        });


        javax.swing.GroupLayout panelStudentLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelStudent);
        panelStudent.setLayout(panelStudentLayout);
        panelStudentLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelStudentLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, panelStudentLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(lblStudent, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 740, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(btnBackUp)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(btnEdit)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(btnBlock)
            .addGap(2, 2, 2))
        );
        panelStudentLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            panelStudentLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(lblStudent, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(btnBackUp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(btnEdit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(btnBlock, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );


        panelStudentHolder.add(panelStudent);

    }
}
```

This is where my problem occurred:

```
btnView.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                System.out.println(" "+lblStudent.getText());
```

//Here it always gives me the last value of my list.
                }
            });

[image: When ever I clicked the buttons it always gives me the ID of the bottom one.]

Comment: Create a custom component which can be used to maintain a encapsulated reference to all the components you are managing for a single line.  Use buttons instead of labels and mouse listeners

Comment: I already solved my first problem. Now only the Layout, when try to change `panelStudentHolder.add(panelStudent);` into `panelStudentHolder.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelStudent, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));` it says that **BoxLayout can't be shared**

Comment: *"On more thing,.."* You can ask as many questions as you like, but put each on a separate Q&A thread, so they are useful to later visitors. To make each question more useful, include a [mcve] specific to that problem. Also: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, **select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.**

Answer (score 0):

for the second part, 
you can set the background color to the panel,

and for making shrink,
give minsize, maxsize and preferred size to panel that should solve the 2nd problem

you can also use box layout that my help.

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)